# Is it possible to disable a PrimeFaces AccordionPanel tab animation?

Tags: javascript, animation, primefaces

The animation happens when you expand or collapse a tab within an AccordionPnel and it can get very sluggish in a busy app and I would like to get rid of it. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May be this can help you,

```
<p:accordionPanel>
    <p:effect event="click" speed="1000" type="highlight"/>
        <p:tab title="1"></p:tab>
        <p:tab title="2"></p:tab>
        <p:tab title="3"></p:tab>
</p:accordionPanel>
```

speed in ms and type is the animation effect do you want.

Comment: Thank you! I tried something very very similar with the effect before but it didn't do exactly what I wanted. Come to find out that the speed I was setting was not the right number :)... Your example doesn't work if you CLICK the tab by the way but when data is loaded at least it doesn't do the animation which is what I want for now.